# Muting/unmutting & changing volume via Web Audio API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have a few quick questions regarding the Web Audio API.   I am developing in JavaScript (AngularJS).

A great demo app that I am using is at:
https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html

Once I grant access to my audio microphone in my Chrome browser, using the Audio API, is there a way to:

1. Mute and un-mute the microphone?
2. Manually changing the microphone volume from JavaScript?
3. An Audio API function returning a Boolean flag (or any object)
   letting me know if the microphone is inaccessible (not working)?

I have found a few links on StackOverflow, but they have not given me the key information that I can use for my need:

- [Volume control with Web Audio API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129754/volume-control-with-web-audio-api)
- [Mute microphone in speakers but still be able to analyze (createAnalyser) with Web Audio Api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482708/mute-microphone-in-speakers-but-still-be-able-to-analyze-createanalyser-with-w)
- [How to mute all sound in a page with JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044761/how-to-mute-all-sound-in-a-page-with-js)

Answer (score 5):

1) Just run the MediaStreamSource node through a Gain node, and set gain to 0 or 1 to mute or unmute.

2) Ditto.  Just use the same gain node.

3) Not really - what do you mean by "not working"?  If it's really not working, you'll never get the stream.